# How do I (properly) invoke a systemd service from udev with an argument?

Tags: systemd, udev

I'm trying to trigger a systemd service from udev when a USB storage device is inserted, and pass device info (the name) to my service which will feed it to a script.

I have created a udev rule(`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-foo.rules`):

`ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", TAG+="systemd", PROGRAM="/bin/systemd-escape -p %k", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="bar@%c.service"`

My systemd service (`/etc/systemd/system/bar.service`) is relatively basic:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script to do stuff with inserted device.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/bin/usbhook %I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I check `/var/log/syslog` on USB drive insertion, I see the drive identified by the machine, but my systemd service does not launch:

```
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.190520] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55a5, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.190547] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.190560] usb 1-1: Product: Cruzer Snap
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.190571] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.190584] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 4C530000180521234567
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.211636] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan  1 18:58:18 metapi kernel: [ 4542.225388] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 22: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1"
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 22 was not an MTP device
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 22: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1"
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 22 was not an MTP device
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.230653] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Snap      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.232528] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.234365] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.234392] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.235109] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.236616] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan  1 18:58:19 metapi kernel: [ 4543.266857]  sda: sda1
Jan  1 18:58:20 metapi kernel: [ 4543.274096] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Note that I believe my udev rules and systemd script should flow properly. If I replace my udev rules with `ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="bar.service"`, which doesn't pass an argument, the systemd script launches:

```
...
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.274286] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.275523] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.276057] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.276081] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.276840] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.309435]  sda: sda1
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi kernel: [ 4850.316819] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jan  1 19:03:27 metapi systemd[1]: Starting Script to do stuff with inserted device....
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an argument.  Services *do not have* arguments.  That's an *instance name* for a *template unit* …

… that you do not have.  You are attempting to start an instance `bar@sda.service`, but you do not have a `bar@.service` template service unit to be instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to put an '@' into the service name. like this:

`sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/bar.service /etc/systemd/system/bar@.service`

in this tutorial, there was also an '@' put into the name in order to pass arguments: http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html