# have script triggered by udev that runs forever

Tags: systemd, usb, logs, udev

I need to log output from `/dev/ttyUSB0`. This is how I start the start-log script on a connection

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/udev/rules.d $ cat 50-text-log.rules 
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", RUN+="/bin/bash /scripts/start-log"
```

all it essentially does is cat `/dev/ttyUSB0 > somefile`, besides figuring out the path in /dev

but it will result into this message from `service udev status`

```
raspberrypi systemd-udevd[4990]: Spawned process '/bin/bash /scripts/start-log' [5018] is taking longer than 59s to complete
```

I have tried this: [How to run long time process on Udev event?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243648)

By doing a double fork it already stops after 8 seconds, making it even worse. Changing the cgroup like this: `echo $$ >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks` (tried to repllicate what was described in the link above in bash) does not change a thing, still exists after 8 seconds.

How can I start a script that may run forever when my USB device connects?

Or how can this be done with a .device file in `/etc/systemd/system` ("device unit")? There is so little information on this.

Comment: If you don't want to learn about systemd's quirks, you can try the first suggestion from the link: start your script with `at now`.

Comment: thanks. I have been trying to follow this tutorial: http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html But I ended up having this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559833/how-do-i-properly-invoke-a-systemd-service-from-udev-with-an-argument. I'm going to use `at now` because this is ridiculous

Comment: solved: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581834/227331

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring this stuff with systemd services out.

---

Here is the old stuff that could not run for more than 59 seconds:

**old udev rule**

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-text-log.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", RUN+="/bin/bash /scripts/start-log"
```

**old script**

/scripts/start-log

```bsh
BASENAME="$(basename $DEVPATH)"
DEVICE="/dev/$BASENAME"
cat "${DEVICE}" >> somefile
```

---

Whereas this has been running for 15 minutes now or something:

**new udev rule**

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-text-log.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="log@$env{DEVPATH}.service"
```

$env{DEVPATH} will be passed to the service as regular command line arg in the $1 bash variable

**new service**

/etc/systemd/system/log@.service

```bsh
[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0
GuessMainPID=false
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/scripts/start-log %I"
```

or maybe use `TimeoutSec=infinity`, looks like that's the newer variation of setting to run forever. But since `=0` works for me I didn't try. (see `man systemd.service` and go down to `TimeoutStopSec=` which is configured over the shorthand of `TimeoutSec=`). And I think I also needed to reboot.

**new script**

```bsh
DEVPATH=$1
BASENAME="$(basename $DEVPATH)"
DEVICE="/dev/$BASENAME"
cat "${DEVICE}" >> somefile
```

The old environment variable is not available anymore, have to get it over the arguments

Comment: The important part, that this glosses over, is that the long-running process is no longer being spawned by udev.  udev is explicitly designed _not_ to spawn long-running processes.